# Cannot send email from asp.net using godaddy professional email account

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, shared-hosting

I have an asp.net web application that has an enquiry page from which i want to send the enquiries to my gmail account, I'm using godaddy professional email account for sending mail from the webpage.
But it doesn't send the email for reasons unknown to me.

This is my front end code:

```
    <form id="contactform" name="contact_form" runat="server">
    <input type="text" id="form_name" value="" runat="server" placeholder="Your Name*" required=""/>
    <input type="email" id="form_email" value="" runat="server" placeholder="Your Mail*" required=""/>
    <input type="text" id="form_phone" value="" runat="server" placeholder="Phone"/>
    <textarea id="form_message" runat="server" placeholder="Your Message.." required=""></textarea>
    <input id="form_botcheck" name="form_botcheck" type="hidden" value=""/>
    <asp:Button CssClass="thm-btn bg-cl-1" runat="server" id="send" Text="Send" OnClick="send_Click" />                        
    </form>'
```

This is my code behind.
I'm using...

```
System.Net;
System.Net.Mail;

// .......

    $public static void SendEmail(string emailbody)
    {
    //email code snippet
    
    // Specify the from and to email address
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("mymail@mydomain.com", "mymail@gmail.com");
    // Specify the email body
    mailMessage.Body = emailbody;
    // Specify the email Subject
    mailMessage.Subject = "Enquiry";
    
    // Specify the SMTP server name and port number
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);
    // Specify your mail address and password
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
    {
    UserName = "mymail@mydomain.com",
    Password = "mypassword"
    };
    // Gmail works on SSL, so set this property to true
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
    // Finall send the email message using Send() method
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
    
    protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
    try
    {
    String str1 = form_name.Value;
    String str2 = form_email.Value;
    String str3 = form_phone.Value;
    String str4 = form_message.Value;
    
    String emailbody = "Name : " + str1 + "\r\n" + "e-mail : " + str2 + "\r\n" + "Contact Number : " + str3 + "\r\n" + "Message : " + str4 + "\r\n";
    
    SendEmail(emailbody);
    
    form_name.Value = "";
    form_email.Value = "";
    form_phone.Value = "";
    form_message.Value = "";
    
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "alert('Your Enquiry has been submitted');", true);
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    catch (Exception em) { Response.Write(em.Message); }
    }
    else
    {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "alert('Please enter the required information and submit');", true);
    }            
    }
```

This code worked 1-2 years back when I worked on another project.

Comment: `System.Net.Mail` is not recommended, it's better to switch to MailKit

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: No error message, just the page gets refreshed. Doesn't even trigger the Clientscript

Comment: Did you actually debug the page? Verify that it reaches the method to send the email? Tried checking to see if Go Daddy's servers require SSL?

Comment: Yes I did debug...it executes the method and regarding the SSL I've tried it both.

Comment: You're saying it gets all the way to `smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);` and that line runs without exception?

Comment: I've uploaded it to shared hosting, and it just refreshes the page nothing else